# Product of Doublet and Arbitrary Function

Tags: continuous-signals, laplace-transform, dirac-delta-impulse

We know that the product of the delta function and another function samples the latter function. That is,
$$
\delta(t-\tau)f(t)=\delta(t-\tau)f(\tau)
$$

Does the doublet function retain this same property? That is, does the following hold true:
$$
\delta'(t-\tau)f(t)=\delta'(t-\tau)f(\tau)
$$
My reasoning is that $\delta'(t-\tau)$ is only nonzero at $\tau$, and therefore the value of $f$ at any time other than $\tau$ does not matter, in the same manner as the delta function product.

One of this issues I have with this result though is that computing the Laplace transform of the doublet function does not seem to work out.
$$
\mathcal{L}\{\delta'(t)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta'(t)e^{-st}dt 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta'(t)e^{-s\times0}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta'(t)dt = 0
$$
The final integral is zero since the doublet function is odd. However, we know that since the doublet is the derivative of the delta, its Laplace transform must be $\mathcal{L}\{\delta'(t)\}=s$.

I would appreciate if someone could offer some insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first equation is correct. For derivatives of the Dirac delta impulse you get slightly more involved expressions. For $\delta'(t)$ the following holds:

$$f(t)\delta'(t)=f(0)\delta'(t)-f'(0)\delta(t)\tag{1}$$

Of course we assume that $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$ are continuous at $t=0$.

With $(1)$ you obtain the correct result for the Laplace transform of $\delta'(t)$:

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(t)e^{-st}dt&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\big[\delta'(t)e^{-s\cdot 0}+se^{-s\cdot 0}\delta(t)\big]dt\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(t)dt+s\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t)dt\\&=s\end{align}$$

The general formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative of the Dirac delta impulse is [1]

$$f(t)\delta^{(n)}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(0)\delta^{(n-k)}(t)\tag{2}$$

[1] A. Papoulis, *The Fourier Integral and Its Applications,* p. 274.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain where the minus sign comes from in equation (1)? At first I thought you were using the derivative product rule, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: @LetterSized: You're right: $[f(t)\delta(t)]'=f'(t)\delta(t)+f(t)\delta'(t)$, and $[f(t)\delta(t)]'=f(0)\delta'(t)$, which results in Eq. $(1)$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Comment: "Your first equation is correct" well. I'd call it ok, maybe not correct

Comment: @LaurentDuval: I would say it's perfectly correct if interpreted correctly. Of course, what it means is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\delta(t-\tau)\phi(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)\phi(t)dt$$

Comment: As a shorthand, then, I am perfectly ok

Answer (score 4):

First, the Dirac delta and its "derivatives" are not traditional functions, and we ought not to say that they are valued at $\tau$ with $-\infty$ or  with $+\infty$ (or possessing both values).

Second, this "[unit doublet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_doublet)" could however shape some intuition on what happens when we perform some operation (product, convolution, etc.) with them. And  this can be used as a mnemonic. You can read for instance a couple of answers at [What is the first derivative of Dirac delta function?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/68732/15892)

Third, let's not forget conditions. This kind of product  $\delta\times f$ is not generic. It requires some conditions on $f$. Classically, $f$ should be a smooth enough function, unless you can get weird and incorrect results. For once, it is very difficult to make sense of an expression like $\delta^2$.

Comment: Even though $\delta(t)$ is not defined at $t=0$, we can certainly say that $\delta(t)=0$ for all $t\neq{}0$, no? Hence why (assuming $f$ is sufficiently smooth) the product of a delta (and its derivatives) with $f$ only depends on the behavior of $f$ at $t=0$. Though I agree with points 2 and 3. I could have better specified $f$, but there's a reason why I posted this question here and not the math stack exchange :).

Comment: Saying something precise about a non-function is out of my grasp. It may depend on the test function space you choose.   I however would be ok, in practice, to consider the Dirac ti be zero almost everywhere